# Independent horizontal/vertical border-radius declarations not animating in Safari

Tags: css, animation, safari, webkit

I'm working on an animation that will show the changing of the phases of the Moon. To do this, I have a circular parent container set to `overflow:hidden` and three child elements that animate within - they creat the light and shadow of the sides of the Moon. I'm animating the horizontal and vertical border-radii pixel dimensions of the child elements independently to mimic the rotation of a sphere. *(see demo below)*

This approach works great in Chrome and Firefox but Safari is ignoring the independent horizontal / vertical pixel declarations on `border-radius` when they're animated ex. `border-radius: 0px/100px;`

Does Safari just not support animating separate horizontal and vertical `border-radius` declarations or am I missing something?

I've added `-webkit-` prefixes to everything I could and still no-go.

Code is too much to paste here so here's a [CodePen.](http://codepen.io/sloanal/pen/YqRXQz)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Never found an answer to the specific question posed above but found a lighter solution that achieves the desired effect. By rotating a circular div on the Y axis using `transform: rotateY(90deg);` I was able to successfully simulate the shadow movement. See here:

Comment: http://codepen.io/sloanal/pen/mPQYpy